# git push operation error

Tags: git, github

i am bit new to git. when i try to push files to remote repo i'm getting the following errors, i was gone through lots of googling but not get proper answer. anybody please help.

> ***Note: i have some updated files in remote repo added by others***

the steps i followed to push

1. i have a "sample.txt" in my local repo
2. i added and committed that file, now my working directory is clean.
3. Now i tried

   ```
   $ git push sample master
   ```

   **Error:**

   > To github.com:xxxxxx/sample.git
   >   ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
   >   error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:xxxxx/sample.git'
   >   hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
   >   hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
   >   hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
   >   hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
   >   hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.`

> ***Note: i have some updated files in remote repo added by others***

[For reference please check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QIyT.png)

what could be the possible solution?, kindly explain with an example

Comment: Did you try reading the information in the error message?

Comment: yes, i read and i tried fetching, pulling bot nothing works

Comment: Then show what you've tried and precisely what happened, **as text**.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, i got this error while pushing `$ git pull sample master
From https://github.com/kirankv369/sample
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned the `git pull` error following in comment section here:

> branch master -> FETCH_HEAD * [new branch] master -> sample/master fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories

So, you need to Pull with git flag *`allow-unrelated-histories`*. Then do Push.

```
$ git pull sample master --allow-unrelated-histories
$ git push sample master
```

> --allow-unrelated-histories:
>   By default, git merge command refuses to merge histories that do not share a common ancestor. This option can be used to override this safety when merging histories of two projects that started their lives independently. As that is a very rare occasion, no configuration variable to enable this by default exists and will not be added.

[More](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#git-merge---allow-unrelated-histories)

Comment: i tried pull, i got error:  ** `* branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
 * [new branch]      master     -> sample/master
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories**`

Comment: Try `git pull sample master --allow-unrelated-histories`

Comment: could you explain "--allow-unrelated-histories"